# Using primitive roots to solve congruences.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

**Question.** Solve $7x^5 = 3 \bmod 19$ using primitive roots.

I know the procedure to work this out. We multiply through the inverse of $7\bmod 19$, show that $2$ is a primitive root $\bmod 19$ and then write everything in terms of powers of $2$. Doing so, we obtain $$2^{5i}\equiv 2^7\bmod 19\Rightarrow 5i\equiv 7\bmod 18\Rightarrow i\equiv 5\bmod 18.$$Then, the answer is $2^5\equiv 13\bmod 19$. However, it has just come to my realisation that I actually have no idea as to why we must work in modulo $18$, or more generally, $\bmod\varphi(n)$ to work out the $i$. I know that there is some connection between $\Bbb Z/19\Bbb Z$ and $U(19)$ but I cannot quite make it a precise one.

Any clarification would be much appreciated here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mean between $\mathbb Z/1\color{red}8 \mathbb Z$ and $U(19)?\,$  In $U(19)$, $u^{18}=1$.  But not all $n$ have primitive roots

Comment: $U(n)$ has $\phi(n)$ elements, and, if it has a primitive root, it’s cyclic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If p is a prime number and $(a,p)=1$ then we have: 
$$ a^{p-1}\equiv1 (mod p)$$
$$therefor: a^{18}\equiv1 (mod 19)$$
$$7x^5\equiv3 \Longrightarrow 77x^5\equiv33 (mod 19)\Longrightarrow$$
$$x^5\equiv14(mod19) \Longrightarrow (x^5)^{11}\equiv(14)^{11}(mod19)$$
$$(x^{18})^3.x\equiv14^{11}  (mod19)$$
$$x\equiv13\  (mod19)$$